# Something that sticks out

Tags: riddle, word

Back with a Riley riddle

> My prefix is someone that is good at
>   My infix is something that a liquid goes through
>   My suffix is to shout
>   My whole is something that sticks out

Comment: After looking at the answer below, assuming that is the word, nice word! $(+1)$ $\color{orange}{\bigstar}$ :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is just a guess as I was not able to find overlap between the prefix, infix and the suffix but found 4 words that seem to fit the bill:

My prefix is someone that is good at would be:

> a **PRO**

My infix is something that a liquid goes through

> a **TUBE**

My suffix is to shout

> a **RANT**

My whole is something that sticks out:

> **PROTUBERANT**

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, was 4h too late to answer :p